# Parent Content Type Site Columns again getting added to Child Content Type in ContentTypeHub

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-type, timer-jobs, site-column, content-type-hub

I am facing weird issue in ContentTypeHub. Where I have ContentType 'Base'. and then I created new ContentType in Hub i.e 'Test'.its parent contentTypes is 'Base'. Now I have removed unnecessary columns from 'Test' ContentType and Published both the contenType. now after 2-3 months when I checked, these same unwanted columns which I removed from 'Test' ContentType, are being again added to 'Test'. Also, I am deploying these CT through a WSP. after deploying WSP to Farm, these CT's state changes to 'Publish' from 'Republish' and suddenly these CT columns are getting Published to subscriber siteCollection. Due to this every time I have to go to CTHub and Manually delete unwanted columns and again Publish  this CT at Hub level. Not sure if its happenning coz of CT Subscriber Job Please let me know any suggestions to avoid these issues in future and if are able to identify this issue(not sure if its a common behavior of SharePoint2013). Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you design your wsp to deploy these site content types, so, cannot to test that via a wsp.

I created and published site content types as you described in SharePoint UI. In my testing, all worked well. "Test" content type in subscriber site didn't contain the removed columns. So, for this issue, you can try to test in UI, if everything works well, this issue should be about your wsp file.

Comment: I have created Feature for ContentTypes and I am activating this feature on CTHub. do you have any idea of Publishing ContentType at Hub level when WSP deployed. as i mentioned after WSp deployment, my old CT which were published previously are again going into 'Publish' state. and these CT are getting published randomely.